# Azure Stack Portal missing Windows

Tags: azure, azure-stack

Many windows within the Azure Stack Portal do not work for my development kit.
Example: When trying to set the forwarding rules of the load balancer, only an error message is shown:

[image]

The debug console of the browser shows the following error messages:

```
[Microsoft_Azure_Network]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎09‎ ‎AM MsPortalFx/Base/Base.Net 1 Base.Net: readyState: 4
responseJSON: {"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}}
responseText: {"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}}
status: 504
statusText: error
 [object Object]
   "[Microsoft_Azure_Network] "
   "‎5‎:‎49‎:‎09‎ ‎AM"
   "MsPortalFx/Base/Base.Net"
   1
   "Base.Net: readyState: 4
responseJSON: {"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}}
responseText: {"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}}
status: 504
statusText: error
"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      duration: 23378.98019290221,
      failureCause: undefined,
      pathAndQuery: undefined,
      requestId: "7386e5a2-4431-4ebc-b1fb-99ba5992e000",
      sessionId: "9d124fcc6fc944fb890bd814ef5b65c0",
      status: 504,
      statusText: "error",
      type: "GET",
      uri: undefined
   }


[Microsoft_Azure_Network]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎09‎ ‎AM PublicIpAddressBladeResourceSummaryViewModel.onInputsSet PublicIpAddressBladeResourceSummaryViewModel.onInputsSet: Failed to retrieve public ip address with id /subscriptions/8e469791-8110-4291-8b35-df0bc0b336a6/resourceGroups/sf_11/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/PublicIP-LB-FE-0, Reason: _errorData: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"GatewayTimeout\",\"message\":\"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period.\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}},"status":504,"statusText":"error"}
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.FetchDataError","MsPortalFx.Errors.DataError","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: undefined
dataSetName: DataCache:1:1
errorLevel: 2
extension: Microsoft_Azure_Network
handled: undefined
innerErr

[Microsoft_Azure_Network]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎09‎ ‎AM PublicIpAddressDissociateCommandViewModel.onInputsSet PublicIpAddressDissociateCommandViewModel.onInputsSet: Failed to retrieve public ip address with id /subscriptions/8e469791-8110-4291-8b35-df0bc0b336a6/resourceGroups/sf_11/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/PublicIP-LB-FE-0, Reason: _errorData: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"GatewayTimeout\",\"message\":\"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period.\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}},"status":504,"statusText":"error"}
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.FetchDataError","MsPortalFx.Errors.DataError","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: undefined
dataSetName: DataCache:1:1
errorLevel: 2
extension: Microsoft_Azure_Network
handled: undefined
innerErrors: [

[Microsoft_Azure_Network]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎09‎ ‎AM AssetBladeBase.onInputsSet AssetBladeBase.onInputsSet: Failed to get entity with id /subscriptions/8e469791-8110-4291-8b35-df0bc0b336a6/resourceGroups/sf_11/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/PublicIP-LB-FE-0, Reason: _errorData: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"GatewayTimeout\",\"message\":\"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period.\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}},"status":504,"statusText":"error"}
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.FetchDataError","MsPortalFx.Errors.DataError","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: undefined
dataSetName: DataCache:1:1
errorLevel: 2
extension: Microsoft_Azure_Network
handled: undefined
innerErrors: []
message: 
name: Error
source: DataCache:1:1
stack: 
timestamp:

[Microsoft_Azure_Network]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎15‎ ‎AM MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 1 MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter: _errorData: undefined
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.AjaxError","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: {"type":"GET","requestId":"7386e5a2-4431-4ebc-b1fb-99ba5992e000","sessionId":"9d124fcc6fc944fb890bd814ef5b65c0","status":504,"statusText":"error","duration":23401.980222159374}
errorLevel: 2
errorThrown: 
extension: Microsoft_Azure_Network
handled: undefined
innerErrors: []
jqXHR: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"GatewayTimeout\",\"message\":\"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period.\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}},"status":504,"statusText":"error"}
message: ajaxExtended call failed
name: Error
source: undefined
stack

[Microsoft_Azure_Network]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎09‎ ‎AM Extension/Microsoft_Azure_Network/PartType/PublicIpAddress$PublicIpAddressBladeResourceSummaryViewModel PublicIpAddress$PublicIpAddressBladeResourceSummaryViewModel: _errorData: undefined
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: {
  <r>: {
    internal: <Object>,
    container: <o>,
    content: <t>,
    onInputsSetPromise: <t>
  }
}
errorLevel: 2
extension: Microsoft_Azure_Network
handled: undefined
innerErrors: []
message: Part's onInputsSet promise failed.(id: Microsoft_Azure_Network-fx-010-004)
name: Error
source: undefined
stack: 
timestamp: 26160.649118871842
type: MsPortalFx.Errors.Error


[Microsoft_Azure_Network]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎15‎ ‎AM MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 1 MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter: _errorData: undefined
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.AjaxError","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: {"type":"GET","requestId":"7386e5a2-4431-4ebc-b1fb-99ba5992e000","sessionId":"9d124fcc6fc944fb890bd814ef5b65c0","status":504,"statusText":"error","duration":23401.980222159374}
errorLevel: 2
errorThrown: 
extension: Microsoft_Azure_Network
handled: undefined
innerErrors: []
jqXHR: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"GatewayTimeout\",\"message\":\"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period.\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period."}},"status":504,"statusText":"error"}
message: ajaxExtended call failed
name: Error
source: undefined
stack

[fx]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎15‎ ‎AM MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 1 MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter: baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: undefined
errorLevel: 2
extension: HubsExtension
handled: undefined
innerErrors: []
message: The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period. (Code: GatewayTimeout)
name: Error
source: undefined
stack: 
From RPC: Microsoft_Azure_Network -> fx (MsPortalFx.Internal.Constants.RpcMethods.getResource)
(Callstack capturing is not enabled. Use ?trace=diagnostics to enable it.)
timestamp: 144390.14179970548
type: MsPortalFx.Errors.Error

[fx]  ‎5‎:‎49‎:‎15‎ ‎AM MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 1 MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter: baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: undefined
errorLevel: 2
extension: HubsExtension
handled: undefined
innerErrors: []
message: The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Network' within the specified time period. (Code: GatewayTimeout)
name: Error
source: undefined
stack: 
From RPC: Microsoft_Azure_Network -> fx (MsPortalFx.Internal.Constants.RpcMethods.getResource)
(Callstack capturing is not enabled. Use ?trace=diagnostics to enable it.)
timestamp: 144390.14179970548
type: MsPortalFx.Errors.Error
```

I am using Azure Stack Development Kit version 1.0.180103.2

Edit: Other things do not work out as well. For example validation of storage account name:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Microsoft had no direct idea how to fix this, a reinstall of the ASDK solved this issue.
Pay attention that you don't install windows updates. This breaks the ASDK completely.

Comment: I'm in the same boat you're in. It looks like this hasn't been solved after almost a year. It takes several tries before an ASDK deployment TO A SERVER will work for me, and when it does, I get the crying clouds all over the portal, regardless of web browser. Guess I'll try installing the ASDK from scratch a few more times... It's clear Microsoft considers the ASDK a "proof of concept" more than a "run this as your Azure Stack dev environment"- no, your dev environment is another full-on Azure Stack deployment, ASDK is just to play around.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider restarting the VMs AzS-NC01, AzS-WAS01 and AzS-XRP01 and see if that helps. Looks like you are using the older version of ASDK (1.0.180103.2), you may want to use the latest ASDK (Build 20180329.1) version.

Comment: Where do I find the "VMs AzS-NC01, AzS-WAS01 and AzS-XRP01"? They are not available under all ressources in the `https://adminportal.local.azurestack.external/`.

Comment: I suggest you try with the latest ASDK build.

Comment: @BaluJr. they are VMs which you will find running on your ASDK management host - just log in via RDP using AzureAdmin or CloudAdmin accounts and start Hyper-V Manager. The Azure Stack infrastructure VMs are not exposed as VMs in Adminportal (nor Portal, for that matter)

Comment: I will say for me, restarting Azure Stack Dev Kit per the official Microsoft docs did not solve the issue for me.